# Do we want winter hats?

Tags: discussion

> UPDATE: Based on feedback, we have told Stack Exchange that we want hats.  Stay tuned for more information on how this will work...

Last year, Stack Exchange had an event called [Hat Dash](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/) for [gaming.stackexchange.com](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/).  Users could earn "hats" for their gravatar by completing various tasks - very similar to the current badge system.

[image: Hat dash hats]

This year, Stack Exchange is expanding the event to include all sites that wish to participate.

Here's the run down:

- The event will run from 19 December 2012 to 4 January 2013.
- Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on http://winterba.sh. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.
- Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an "I hate hats" option available..
- The only visual change to the site itself will be the presence of the hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.
- We need to let Stack Exchange know by 28 November 2012, so vote away on if you want hats.

Comment: how long will this event last?, my vote strongly depends on this

Comment: @ajax333221 The event is Dec 19 - Jan 4, and the hats go away after that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, we want hats!  Hats are fun!

Answer (score 3):

No, we don't want hats, the site is fine without them.